# Electron + Angular : cannot run unit test

Tags: angular, electron

I have an Electron + angular app.
I could serve or build, but when i ran Unit test I had following errors

> ./node_modules/electron/index.js:1:11-24 - Error: Module not found:
> Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in '...\node_modules\electron'
>
> ./node_modules/electron/index.js:2:13-28 - Error: Module not found:
> Error: Can't resolve 'path' in '..\node_modules\electron'

I found several threads that advise to add

```
  "browser": {
    "fs": false,
    "path": false
  }
```

in package.json.
I did and don't have above errors anymore, but I now have :

> Chrome Headless 99.0.4844.51 (Windows 10) ERROR   An error was thrown
> in afterAll   Uncaught ReferenceError: __dirname is not defined
> ReferenceError: __dirname is not defined
> at Object.2218 (http://localhost:9876/*karma_webpack*/webpack:/node_modules/electron/index.js:4:1)

Any tips?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue with the fs fail (and your solution throws errors for me) but I did solve the __dirname issue.

The problem I had was in the module and target that was being specified in the compiler options.  Evidently, if you target ES modules rather than commonjs it does not generate the definition for you, and not all packages you import support that yet.  You can be using ES modules just by specifying {"type": "module"} in your package.json file.  I may have also changed the tsconfig compiler options so if changing the package.json as below does not fix it on its own, that would be my next stop.

I simply changed that to {"type": "commonjs"} and I believe the problem disappeared for me.  I hope that helps.